# how to iterate over each row in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe like:

```
name       address     result
rishi     los angeles   true
tushar    california    false
keerthi   texas         false
```

I want to iterate through each row of the dataframe and check if result value is "true" or "false"

if true i want to copy the address to another address new column and if false i want to make address new column as "Null"

how to achieve this using pyspark?

result should be

```
name       address     result  address_new
rishi     los angeles   true   los angeles

tushar    california    false   null
keerthi   texas         false   null
```

Comment: isn't it just a `filter()` operation? why do you want to iterate? -- i'd suggest you read about the basics of pyspark. btw, see [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-filter) for `filter`

Comment: @samkart,, sorry i have updated the question now

Comment: you can achieve it with `when()` and `otherwise()`. https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html

Answer (score 1):

This line should work to filter the data:

```
new_df = df[df['result'] == True]
```

In terms of the new address, a list comprehension could be used.

```
df['address_new'] = [df.loc[i]['address'] if df.loc[i] == True else None for i in range(df.shape[0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `when()` for this purpose, I'd suggest reading up on the basics of PySpark. However in your case it would be something like:

```
df = df.withColumn("address_new", when(df.result == true, df.address)
.otherwise(null))
```